# What is a "continuous vector"?

Tags: machine-learning, math, embeddings, vectors, vector-space

I have seen the concept of a "continuous vector" described in the context of embeddings. For instance, [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54045/49134) to a question on embeddings in the context of deep learning. I obviously know what a vector is, but it isn't clear to me what a *continuous* vector is as a mathematical object. What is a "continuous vector"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuous vector simply means that each value of the vector is allowed to be a real number, in contrast of integer values used in other categorical encoding techniques like one-hot encoding (only 0 and 1) or class-value mapping (a different integer per class).

Comment: Oh, ok. I was wondering if that was the case, since that's the most obvious option, but I wasn't sure if it was referring to something else in the context of machine learning. Thanks for the clarification.